# Test condition not work

Tags: python, select, timeout, sys

I'm using python with select and system library here the code :

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                            print_function, unicode_literals)
from select import select
import sys
def main():
    timeout = 5
    print('Please type something: ', end = '')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select([sys.stdin],[],[], timeout)
    k=sys.stdin.readline()
    if k=="f":
        data = sys.stdin.readline()
        print('you entered', data)
    else:
        print('\nSorry, {} seconds timeout expired!'.format(timeout))
        print(k) #see the sys.stdin result
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this program wait the user until put a char 
i put in the program a condition if the user put a char after 5 second so the program stop also if the user give something different of the 'f' char but the problem the condition doesn't work i put a test to see the result of the `sys.stdin` value he give me the 'f char but when i put the result in the if statement the program don't work 
this screenshot of the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pghr9.png)

Can someone give me the reason of this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about the `select` library. But here is an error the immediately caught my eyes.

You read from the input with `k=sys.stdin.readline()`. This means that `k` will contain the complete line, including the `\n` (newline) symbol. So if you press `f + Enter` the value of `k` will be `"f\n"`, not `"f"`. This is the reason why the comparison is always wrong.

It would be best to compare the values with `if k.strip() == "f":`.

---

#### Edit

Just had a quick look into the `select` library. If you want to determine if a timeout happened, you need to work with the return values of the select function. And not read from input directly. Otherwise you will wait regardless if a timeout happened or not.

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but something similar to the following code will work.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from select import select
import sys

timeout = 5
print('Please type something: ', end = '')
sys.stdout.flush()
inputready, _, _ = select([sys.stdin],[],[], timeout)
if inputready:
    k = sys.stdin.readline()
    if k.strip()=="f":
        print("You printed 'f'")
    else:
        print("Not 'f'")
else:
    print('\nSorry, {} seconds timeout expired!'.format(timeout))
```

Comment: yes it's working thanks i'm forget the \n but something not clear in your answer why you add the int

Comment: @Sekmani52 "int"??? Do you mean the variable inputready? That's one of the returns values of select. It tells, if somebody has written to the input or not.

Comment: Nice work. Sekmani52 doesn't have enough rep to upvote yet... but I do. ;)

Comment: @user38034 I'm sorry but my laptop shutdown and i don't edit my answer hhh i will correct my comment i say why you add the `if inputready: ` why not `if k.strip(): `directly I'm testing the code in my machine and is work without the `if inputready: ` and thanks and yes is so helpful

Comment: @Sekmani52 Ok, :-) `if inputready:` is actually the most important thing. If `inputready == False`, then the user hasn't written anything yet. And if you just write `k = sys.stdin.readline()` it will wait until the user has actually written something. This is of course not what you want to achieve. If the user hasn't written anything in the first 5 seconds, you don't want to read the input, you just want to print an error message. At least this is what I think you want to do.

Comment: Ah ok thanks but why if i don't use the inputready nothing change ??

Comment: @Sekmani52 Of course it changes. If you don't use `inputready`, then you'll not get a time out after 5 seconds.